# Crash: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-appcompat

My app crashes below Android 6. Here is my Error log:

```
05-19 12:38:13.682 24304-24304/com.example.find E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.find/com.example.find.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.find.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
```

My styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:titleTextColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppFullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

My Manifest:

```
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <activity android:name=".Time" android:theme="@style/AppFullScreenTheme" android:label="Wysyłaj lokalizację czasowo"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Settings"  android:theme="@style/AppFullScreenTheme" android:label="Ustawienia"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppFullScreenTheme">
```

I was looking for solutions, but they didn't work for me. I know I must change something in styles probably, I tried to do it, but it still doesnt work for me. Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. I have created a new Android Studio project using the "empty activity" template, and added your exact style (copy/paste) to the styles.xml (removing the existing style), and then added the `android:theme` to the manifest for the same "MainActivity" that came with the template. I ran it and it didn't crash. Are you sure you don't have any other style being used? You're going to have to give us a little bit more info in this case, for I cannot repro your crash.

Comment: please paste your mainactivity code

Comment: Post this code: com.example.find.MainActivity.onCreate in particular the line 24.

Comment: My xml activity main here: http://wklejto.pl/836941  and my line 24 is simply         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Hi @AleksandraMiazek, can you also post the content of the `activity_main` layout?